# X509 Extensions

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, x509

How to set Extensions for an x509 certificate, in java, using bouncycastle API?

I managed to do the "Basic Constrains" like this:

```
...
X509V3CertificateGenerator gen = new X509V3CertificateGenerator();
...
boolean crit;
boolean isCa;
gen.addExtension(X509Extensions.BasicConstraints, crit, new BasicConstraints(isCa));
```

However, I can't figure out how to do the same for *IssuerAlternativeName* or *KeyUsage*.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 KeyUsage usage = new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.keyCertSign
        | KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment
        | KeyUsage.dataEncipherment | KeyUsage.cRLSign);
 gen.addExtension(Extension.keyUsage, false, usage);


 GeneralNames issuerAltName = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(new X509Name("CN=somedomain.tld")));
    gen.addExtension(X509Extensions.IssuerAlternativeName, false, issuerAltName);
```